# Initializing malloc'd memory in a way similar to an array literal?

Tags: c

Let's say I've calloc'd some memory for myself:

```
byte *header = calloc(5 + ZHEADERSIZE, sizeof(byte));
```

This gives me an array of 0's. But what if I want to make a custom initialization of the memory? The following code is a fairly detailed initialization for an array literal. Note that it actually contains variables, so I can't just memcpy all of the array over. I'm wondering if I can replicate this style of initialization for a block of memory that is malloc'd out without having to insert them manually.

```
unsigned char zhead[] =
{
    0x00, 37, 0, 218, 0xFF,

    0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04,
    0x14,
    0x00,
    0x00, 0x00,
    0x08, 0x00,
    0x08, 0x03,
    0x64, 0x3c,
    0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD,
    csize, (csize>>8), 0, 0,
    uncsize, (uncsize>>8), 0, 0,
    0x07, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00,
    'r', '/', 'r', '.', 'z', 'i', 'p'
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot *initialize* dynamically allocated memory in C other than to zero using `calloc`. You can however provide a static prototype array from which you *copy* the data:

```
const char prototype[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

int main()
{
   char * data = malloc(sizeof prototype);
   memcpy(data, prototype, sizeof prototype);

   data[1] = 'z'; // fill in custom data
}
```

Comment: And then, of course, fill in the variable sections as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what if your prototype has variables in it, as mine does in the example? Then is your only option really to manually insert them into the memory block by hand?

Comment: @apc: You overwrite the variable parts later. The prototype only contains the common data. If the entire array's content is variable, then you just have to assign it after allocation. Basically, the allocator cannot prefill the memory with a dynamically specified pattern.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks again.